# PHP Oracle oci_num_rows result 0

Tags: php, oracle

I have a question about query in Oracle :

The problem is, the result of `oci_num_rows` is always 0.

and here is my code so far :

```
  $query = "SELECT IP_ADDRESS, STATUS FROM SEIAPPS_IP_ADDRESS WHERE IP_ADDRESS='$ip'";
  $result = oci_parse($c1, $query);
  oci_execute($result);
  echo $found = oci_num_rows($result);
```

To make it sure, I try to clear the condition `"WHERE IP_ADDRESS='$ip'"`. Still same with the result is  0 whereas in my table there are some data.

Any advice ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fetch data from oracle database using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782007/how-to-fetch-data-from-oracle-database-using-php)

Comment: It's not about PDO it's about `oci_num_rows()` function, which does not return number of selected rows. It returns number of affected by a DML statement rows, so in your case it will always return 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function does not return number of rows selected! For `SELECT statements` this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with `oci_fetch*()` functions.

Try this to check either your the credentials of your connection are correct or not.

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/XE");
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();   // For oci_connect errors do not pass a handle
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$query = "SELECT IP_ADDRESS, STATUS FROM SEIAPPS_IP_ADDRESS WHERE IP_ADDRESS='$ip'";
$result = oci_parse($c1, $query);
oci_execute($result);
$numrows = oci_fetch_all($result, $res);
echo $numrows." Rows";
```

Comment: I run out of space on the server with oci_fetch_all.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who fell into this trap, here's a simple summary of what the `oci_fetch_all` method will return.

```
$s = oci_parse($conn, "
          SELECT 1 AS A FROM DUAL 
    UNION SELECT 2 AS A FROM DUAL 
    UNION SELECT 3 AS A FROM DUAL 
    UNION SELECT 4 AS A FROM DUAL
");
oci_execute($s);
echo "records fetched: ". oci_num_rows($s)."\n";

oci_fetch($s);
echo "records fetched: ". oci_num_rows($s)."\n";

oci_fetch($s);
echo "records fetched: ". oci_num_rows($s)."\n";

oci_fetch_all($s, $out);
echo "records fetched: ". oci_num_rows($s)." out count: ". count($out['A']) . "\n";
```

will output:

```
records fetched: 0
records fetched: 1
records fetched: 2
records fetched: 4 out count: 2
```

So `oci_num_rows` is incremental, each call to `oci_fetch` will increment the counter by one (assuming there is at least one more record to fetch), and `oci_fetch_all` will fetch all remaining rows and put them into the `$out` buffer.