# How to properly count number of rows in Oracle using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle9i

I am trying to count the number of rows using PHP. Here is my problem when I test my SQL statement directly to my database it returns three(3) rows, but when I use my PHP script it only returns one(1). What is happening here? I tried adding ***OCI_ASSOC*** cursor but no luck.

```
$existsql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT CLIENTID FROM LCCLIENT WHERE NAME = '". $name ."'");
$existexec = oci_execute($existsql);

if($existexec){
    $existrow = oci_fetch_array($existsql, OCI_ASSOC);
    $existcount = oci_num_rows($existsql);
    echo $existcount; //this returns only 1
}
```

Here is my query I used in the database

> SELECT CLIENTID FROM LCCLIENT WHERE NAME = 'John Doe'

Comment: Show us the query that you have tried directly on database.

Comment: @Tejash please see update I used the same query

Comment: `oci_fetch_array` fetches rows one by one. See http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.oci-fetch-array.htm

Comment: @Tejash how can I count the number of rows?

Comment: Might be the second answer from this SO question will be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957148/php-oracle-oci-num-rows-result-0/18957201

Comment: If you want to **count** number of rows, why don't you do that? Instead of `select clientid from ...` do `select count(*) from ...`

Comment: When you execute queries, use bind variables for security and scalability.  Check the manual or the Oracle guide http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html